# How to Terminate Threads that started within foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service

I started multiple threads by for each loop in my windows service.I didn't mention any name for these threads.How can i terminate these thread.
I use the following code to create threads.

```
 new Thread(() =>
            {
                foreach (MyClass detail in MyclassList)
                {
                    DoWork(detail);
                }

            }).Start();
```

By starting these threads i create a schedule task for each details.Can i dispose this thread after Scheduling is done and How?

Comment: Terminate what? By who? Why "threads"? You're creating just one thread that will process each task sequentially but in parallel with the "main" thread

Comment: Do you mean to kill the threads during execution or just join them?

Comment: After DoWork task completed i like to abort the thread created

Comment: @Satheesh if you abort after `DoWork`, you will only have processed one item out of the list. A better way to do that would be to use `.Take(1)` or similar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forcibly terminating threads is *never* a good idea. What you should really be doing is putting some suitably designed "should I continue" check inside the loop, that you can set to "no" externally. *How* to do that depends a bit more on context... For example:

```
        int shouldExit = 0;
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (MyClass detail in MyclassList)
            {
                if(Thread.VolatileRead(ref shouldExit) != 0) break;
                DoWork(detail);
            }
        }).Start();
        ...
        // to terminate loop:
        Thread.VolatileWrite(ref shouldExit, 1);
```

There are, however, a myriad of ways to sort out a thread-safe exit test; the only slightly tricky thing is keeping hold of some kind of context with access to the thing being checked.

Comment: Am bit confused.By calling new Thread() will create a thread right?.Will the above code terminate this thread or it will terminate the loop.My questions is after DoWork() gets completed like to abort or terminate the Thread.

Comment: @Satheesh the thread terminates *itself* when it reaches the end of the method it was asked to do. Hence: if you want to terminate: simply `break;` out of the loop. My answer presumes you want to request that from **outside** the loop - if you want to terminate from **inside** the loop, it is even simpler - just `break;` out of the loop when you want to exit.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use the `Task` class instead of directly creating a new thread. Then, I would use the builtin TPL cancellation mechanisms. Here is what it would look like.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () =>
  {
    foreach (MyClass detail in MyclassList)
    {
      ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      DoWork(detail);
    }
  }, cts.Token); 

// Do other stuff here.

cts.Cancel(); // Request cancellation.
```